# Defining __str__ and __repr__ for a set container

Tags: python, string, repr

I have been working on a large assignment and I'm almost finished except I need help writing the `__str__` and `__repr__` functions of a Set container.

I have never done this and I have no clue what to do. Searching the internet, I'm still stuck.

I've tried something like:

```
'%s(%r)' % (self.__class__, self)
```

I need to print out a representation like this:

```
'set([ELEMENT_1, ELEMENT_2,..., ELEMENT_N])'
```

My elements are stored in an array class that I wrote the set container around. I access it with a loop like `for item in self` or `if item in self`

Please help?

Comment: This might help you understand
[Stack overflow page talking about the differences between __repr__ and __str__][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the following would work:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'set([%s])' % ', '.join(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/1988505) detailing the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`.

A basic implementation would be something like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'set(%r)' % [item for item in self]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this may be good enough and would take care of both methods:

```
class Set(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.array)

    __str__ = __repr__
```

Comment: "if `__repr__` is defined, and `__str__` is not, the object will behave as though `__str__=__repr__`." - [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/1988505)

Comment: True enough. The main point though was the `{!r}` in the format string which will be replaced with the `repr(self.array)` which, of course, will depend on exactly what it is -- and makes it an object-oriented design.